# Is it safe to listen to Apple earpods at 75% volume?

Tags: audio, headphones

The sensitivity is listed at 109 DB, so I guess 75% volume is about 82 DB, which is pretty safe.

Comment: First of all, decibels are on a logarithmic scale, so 75% of 109dB is not 82dB. Second, please read this article on headphone sensitivity, so you better understand what it means. http://shure.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2991/~/understanding-earphone-%2F-headphone-specifications

Comment: @AndrewLarsson: A percentage given on a computer or phone GUI is neither linear. It is probably a frontend to a very logarithmic scale, but with totally different coeficients. A linear acting volume slider would make no sense at all, as the ear is a logarithmic sensing receiver.

Comment: I think that 75% may be pushing it a bit. Keep in mind that headphones are always safer to use than EarPods, which are inserted right up next to the eardrums.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a little bit off topic, I'll provide some thoughts here.

1. you can't expect the percentage scaling directly with dB SPL. While both are surely nonlinear inside the affected electronics, the nonlinearity of Apple's percentage may not be logarithmic but dB SPL are.
2. sensitivity is dB SPL at 1 V. This usually has not much to do with the sound pressure level, your headset produces at 100%.
3. audio files and sounds from apps and programs may be scaled differently. Computer equipment and phones usually do not provide a compressor algorithm, so a setting of 75% yields totally different sound pressure levels for different sound sources.

Conclusion: No, it is not necessary safe to listen at 75%. It may or may be not healthy.